# Angular can you make the whole table row clickable in a tree table?

Tags: angular, primeng

Hello I would like to make the whole tr clickable inside my tree table in angular. I am using the treetable from PrimeNG.
Currently I can only click on the button to expand my table row. Now I would like to be able to click on the whole table row:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
            <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></i>
        </a>

        <td>
            {{Partij.Partij.sBedrijfsNaam}}
        </td>
        <td><p-dropdown [options]="Bedrijfstype" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sBedrijfsType"></p-dropdown></td>
        <td><p-dropdown [options]="Status" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sStatus"></p-dropdown></td>
        <td><p-dropdown [options]="Rekeningbank" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sRekBank"></p-dropdown></td>
</tr>
```

Now I can only click in the above td how can I make it so I can click in the whole tr?

Comment: Move `pRowToggler` to the `tr` element?

Comment: Thanks that worked but now if I select something in the dropdown it will also expand the table row

Answer (score 0):

Move `pRowToggler` to the row element and make sure that dropdowns don't propagate any click events by adding `$event.stopPropagation()` like this:

```
<tr [pRowToggler]="rowData">
<td>
  <a href="#">
    <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></i>
  </a>

<td>
    {{Partij.Partij.sBedrijfsNaam}}
</td>
<td><p-dropdown [options]="Bedrijfstype" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sBedrijfsType" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></p-dropdown></td>
<td><p-dropdown [options]="Status" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sStatus" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></p-dropdown></td>
<td><p-dropdown [options]="Rekeningbank" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sRekBank" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></p-dropdown></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but now I can only open my dropdown box once?

Comment: I don't know how their dropdown is built but that seems like a shit one if you can't even stop propagation from it :D Maybe try @ferie's answer and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to the `a` tags and make it as big as the first `td` in CSS.

Then you can trigger an event on each `tr`:

```
<tr (click)="expanded = !expanded" class="clickable">
    /* ... */
</tr>
```

or on any other `td`s:

```
...
<td class="clickable">
    <p-dropdown
        [options]="Bedrijfstype"
        [(ngModel)]="Partij.Partij.sBedrijfsType"
        (click)="expanded = !expanded"
    ></p-dropdown>
</td>
...
```

Remember to give a class to the `tr`s or the `td`s so you can give them a CSS rule like the following to highlight they are clickable:

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: thanks but if I try this I keep getting this error in my console:  Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: What do you cannot assign?